# looking for edible paper

Tags: food-science

At some point I came across some edible paper.  I don't know which company makes it or where to find it?  I think I recall that it was possible to write on it.  I encountered it back in the '80's.  The texture was semi-flexible, nothing like the little round cracker-like paper given in church.

Comment: Can you share how you came across it?  Just curious cause if it was an asian food application or something else it might help people come up with the best answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Belgium, we have something that is called 'candy paper' and a package looks like [this](http://www.realdutchfood.com/UserFiles/Images/Large/snoeppapier.JPG).
It's a thin sheet of paper, about the size of a bill. It's thinner than the outer part of [this](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/stad/images/thumb/3/3d/Hosties.jpg/300px-Hosties.jpg), but it has a similar texture.

There are multiple manufacturers and you can buy it here in almost every supermarket/candy shop.

I don't know if you can write on it, I think so, but I don't see why you would like to eat ink.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you're talking about edible rice paper. I know it is used in popular Asian candys, such as the White Rabbit Creamy Candy which was a childhood favorite of mine and I've also used rice paper while making a candy dessert called Turrones de casuy, a Filipino nougat candy which is wrapped in rice paper sheet. You can order from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00024WNVI) or [here](http://www.kopykake.com/in_edible_rice_paper.html) for variety.

Comment: Vietnamese egg rolls (Chả giò) are traditionally made with rice paper. You might also try filo dough, if you're not wholly into the paper thing. It's not paper, but it's paper-like.